# How to pass data from php to a c++ desktop application using sockets?

Tags: php, c++, sockets

I am writing a firefox extension making use of XUL and javascript. I need to send data to a c++ desktop application on click of the firefox extension.

So I call for a php page from javascript. My idea is to use sockets to communicate to c++ desktop application.I have tried implementing the php sockets code available at the php tutorials but did not get the way to do this communication(from php to c++)

Please suggest ways/code to do this.

Comment: where's the need to add a php layer on top of xul & javascript? why not communicate directly from the extension with the c++ app?

Comment: You provided no code for your solution, that's basically asking someone else to write it for you. What's the problem?

Comment: Please can you suggest how this can be done.. i am not good at c++

Comment: Let me put my idea clearly..Onclick of the firefox extension(written in XUL), a javascript function is called which loads a php page. I need to send some parameters to a c++ application which launches based on the parameters. My code works fine till calling a php page. Then i am not sure what to do.

Comment: example c++ code: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/clientserver.html#simpleserver